# Could iOS Kill an App in the Background?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiapplicationdelegate

While the device is powered on, is it possible for iOS to automatically terminate my app (calling `applicationWillTerminate:`) while it's in the background?

I'm also curious what happens in two other cases, three in total:

1. Device is powered on
2. Device is powered off
3. Device loses battery

I'm asking because I want to know how often `applicationWillTerminate:` is likely to get called. I want to know this because that's where I'm registering for remote notifications. And if there's a failure sending the device token to the server, I want to know how likely it is that that method will get called again (i.e., retry sending the device token to the server).

Answer (score 7):

If your application supports multitasking (the default for anything linked against iOS 4.0+), this method will almost never be called. The documentation says it *may* be called in cases where the application is running in the background and the system wants to terminate. However, in my experience, I've only ever seen this actually called when running a music app that's actively playing music in the background and the system is jettisoning everything. In cases where I have background tasks running (not music, but short-term background tasks), I've seen the app terminated without this method being called.

I wouldn't ever rely on this being called and try and do all the clean-up you need to do in your delegate methods for transitioning into the background and your background task completion blocks (which do get executed for at least a few seconds before the app gets jettisoned).

Answer (score 5):

Not only can iOS terminate your app automatically, but the user can kill it manually. In fact, the *only* time the user can kill your app is when it's in the background. Furthermore, when your app is "in the background" it's more likely to be suspended than actually running, so don't count on doing a lot of processing when you're not the foreground app.

As for how *likely* it is that you'll get `-applicationWillTerminate:`, that'll depend on the user and how they're using their device. You should handle it appropriately when you get it, and go about your business otherwise.

Comment: +1. I see a lot of users who kill apps because they believe it saves memory. It's good policy to play nice and use `applicationWillTerminate:` to account for (incorrect) users who kill your app.

Comment: What happens when the user kills my app before I finish what I have to do, say saving a Core Data database? What can I do?

Comment: @acecapades As per the documentation, you will have roughly 5 seconds to save your data within the `applicationWillTerminate` method.

Answer (score 3):

When memory is running low, iOS *can* shut down your app, calling `applicationWillTerminate`.

The [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786) say this about the method:

> ... However, this method may be called in situations where the application is running in the background (not suspended) and the system needs to terminate it for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [iOS Developer Library : iOS App Programming Guide : App Termination](http://j.mp/J9DfiK).